# How do I translate an encoded error message from PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, opencart

I'm getting this error from my PHP based shop script:

> {"error":"\u0422\u0440\u0435\u0431\u0443\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u043a\u0430 \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0430!"}

How do I translate this? The site is in Russian, if that might help.

Comment: Those are Unicode escape codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: It's JSON. JSON-decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that there's some file that needs loading...

In russian: Требуется загрузка файла

Translation: You need to load a file

You can use http://www.branah.com/unicode-converter to convert your messages from unicode to text next time.

Good luck!

Comment: That is *not* "Unicode". It's Javascript/JSON string-style Unicode escape sequences, which is something else.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that does it, i would upvote by i lack the rep

Comment: No prob :) Hope you can solve now whatever problem your are facing

Comment: @AudioTroubler If the answer helped, you should accept it (click the check mark to the left). That way the person who answered it can get credit for it.